# How to add CONSTRAINT and default value for snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have sql query like below

```
ALTER TABLE "db"."Ft" ADD  CONSTRAINT "Dname"  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR "cname"
```

when I am trying to execute above code in snowflake .
I am getting error like " `unexpected 'DEFAULT`'.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately such operation is not possible.

> [ALTER TABLE … ALTER COLUMN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table-column.html#alter-table-alter-column)
>
> The following table describes the supported/unsupported actions for modifying column properties:
>
> **Add a default for a column.    Unsupported**

---

Alternative is table recreation with new definition containing DEFAULT and repopulating data.

Another option is adding new column, copying data and renaming column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Ft ADD COLUMN cnmame2 STRING NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
UPDATE TABLE dbo.Ft SET cname2 = cname;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Ft DROP COLUMN cname;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Ft RENAME COLUMN cname2 to cname;
```